# Is it possible to use egrep to match numbers within a range?

Tags: regex, grep, integer

Is there a way to `grep`/`egrep` between two sets of numbers?

```
egrep "SomeText [19999-22000]" /some/file.txt
```

It's not returning the values. I expect:

```
SomeText 19999 ffuuu  
SomeText 20001 ffuuu  
SomeText 21000 ffuuu
```

Comment: This is off-topic for SO; belongs on [su]

Comment: @JimGarrison Grep and regular expressions are both on-topic here on Stack Overflow. That's why we have tags for them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

regex is not the right tool for math stuff (although sometimes it can do), in your case, try the awk:

```
awk '$2>=19999 && $2<=22000' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the range function `,` with `awk`

```
awk '$2=="19999",$2=="22000"' file
SomeText 19999 ffuuu
SomeText 20001 ffuuu
SomeText 21000 ffuuu
```